# compressing a set of binary strings with fixed length

Tags: data-structures, strings, sets

I'm looking for a data structure / algorithm to store an unordered set `S` of binary strings of a fixed length `n` (i.e. all matching the following regular expression: `[01]{n}`).

Insertion and lookup ("Is element `x` in the `S`?") should maximally take polynomial time to `|S|`.

The space complexity should be logarithmic to `|S|` for large sets. In other words, the space should not be exponential to `n` if for example `2^n / 2` random and unique strings are inserted, but polynomial to `n`.

Is such a thing known to exist?

Comment: Do you allow errors in your lookup queries? Otherwise, it is easy to prove that what you are asking for is impossible.

Comment: No, errors are not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $S$ consists of $m$ strings in $\{0,1\}^n$ and we don't allow query arrows. Any two different sets $S_1,S_2 \subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ of size $m$ respond differently to some lookup query: there must be some $x \in S_1\setminus S_2$, for example, and the lookup of $x$ should succeed in $S_1$ and fail in $S_2$. For this reason, the contents of your data structure should be different for $S_1,S_2$. Since there are $\binom{2^n}{m}$ different choices for $S$, any data structure supporting all of them should have at least $\binom{2^n}{m}$ different settings. In particular, if you use $M$ bits to store it then $2^M \geq \binom{2^n}{m}$. When $m = 2^n/2$, for example, this forces $M \geq 2^n - O(n) = 2m - O(\log m)$.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you very much. However, I have one more question: Since your proof considers the worst case, would it be possible to be better on average for random strings with some special compression? Perhaps with something like the following? `n = 3; S1 = [001,100,101,110,111] = [001,1..]; S2 = [001,100,101,110] = [001,10.,110]`

Comment: The same argument shows that if, for example, you only want your data structure to work for an $\alpha$ fraction of sets $S$ (of your choice!), then you only save $-\log_2 \alpha$ bits. For example, you can save a mere $\log n$ bits by restricting to a $1/n$ fraction of sets. So average case doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Of course, if the set of strings is compressible (in the sense that the $k$-th order empirical entropy is less than the $0$-order entropy), then there are techniques which can help you there, and give you sublinear query time. But actually, since the question only asked for a query time polynomial in $|S|$, using an off-the-shelf compression program will do the job.